# Excel formula bar default font

Tags: microsoft-excel, fonts, microsoft-excel-2013

It's hard to see a leading negative sign on the Excel formula bar. For example, if I want a formula to be =-A1+B2 (instead of =B2-A1) the default font makes it easy to miss.

How can I change the font of the Excel formula bar in Office 2013. Note this [linked answer](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-customize/change-the-font-size-and-type-on-the-formula-bar/e1286490-82dc-47b5-a400-993c508513ad?auth=1) does not work for me because I have no Office Button. I am using Office 2013 on Windows 7.

Second but rhetorical question: why is the default font completely unsuitable for formulas in Excel and this stackexchange website?

Comment: You should only ask one question per post. Nothing personal, but your second question should be removed anyway because it is an opinion and not an actual problem.

Comment: Agree with @charlie - there's no way to even answer the second part.

Comment: https://www.google.ca/search?q=define+rhetorical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it in File > Options > General, where it is called the "default" font.

Comment: Does this also change the font of cells? Column letters and row numbers? What about sheet tabs? Or the ribbon?